# Wordpress how much RAM to see 14 000 posts on backend

Tags: php, wordpress

Recently i had to make a website on wordpress CMS.
One of things i had to do was to import lot's of data about products to make them searchable. I had decided to build those products data into Wordpress structure so i created custom post type and build all product details using ACF.

I imported around 14 000 products, but when i decided to see them on backend i've got  an error
"Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted"

Is there a way to overcome this ? 
Or should I move Products data to separate tables ?
How wordpress Ram consumption scales with Number of Posts ?

Comment: Who would or would want to look at all 14,000 products on one page. Maybe you should explore using some pagination

Comment: Maybe I was unclear this was on backend page where pagination is done by design. that's why i am asking this question.
I understand that presenting soo much results on one page is pointless @RiggsFolly

Comment: Well then it depends on how you have done the pagination. Maybe if you show some code, we could be more constructive

Comment: Wordpress have built in pagination for custom post types. Thats why i am asking why when i have pagination, I've got Memory exhaust error.
More over when i debug code with Xdebug it was thrown inside of wp-db.php file. And how much more RAM wordpress needs when quantity of posts rises ?